# Can not access to the nth product's variation ( n > 1) programmatically

Tags: 8, commerce

I have a product type called `gift` with 3 different variations.

I add an attribute to it so that a user can choose a custom variation based on the attribute, attribute (A, B, C).

I also have a custom checkout pane, If a user choose the first variation (by choosing the attribute), i can access the variation that is selected. for example by using 2 lines of code below:

```
<?php
$variations = $gift->variations->getEntity();
?>
```

Or

```
<?php
$gift->variations->target_id
?>
```

But if a user choose another variations except the first variation (for example: variation B), I can not access to that variation.

```
<?php
public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $pane_form['#order_entity'] = $this->order;

    $order_items = $this->order->getItems();
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem $item */
    $item = $order_items[0];
    $gift = $item->getPurchasedEntity();
    $gift = Product::load($gift->id());

    $variations = $gift->variations->getEntity(); // Just works for first variation
    drupal_set_message('bundle: ' . $variations->bundle());

    // This line of code works for just first variation too
    // $id = $gift->variations->target_id;
}
?>
```

Regards

Comment: Hi and welcome. It is unclear what you want. Is this a bug report, or you you want to know how to access the variation? Could you please phrase a question?

Comment: What does `$gift->variations[1]->getEntity()` get you?

Comment: If @Clive is right, I suppose `$gift->variations->referencedEntities();` should also return an array of entities.

Comment: @Neograph734, I was wrong and thought that it's a bug. Bojanz corrected and told me `$item->getPurchasedEntity()` is the product variation, not the product. [link](https://www.drupal.org/node/2893842#comment-12163314).

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I wanted to get attributes attached to the current variation. According to Bojanz' answer: https://www.drupal.org/node/2893842#comment-12163314, there was no need to use `$gift->variations`. Bojanz corrected and told me `$item->getPurchasedEntity()` is the product variation, not the product

So the code would be:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $pane_form['#order_entity'] = $this->order;

    $order_items = $this->order->getItems();
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderItem $item */
    $item = $order_items[count($order_items) - 1]; // the last item added to the order
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation $gift */
    $gift = $item->getPurchasedEntity();
    $attribute = $gift->getAttributeValue('attribute_gift_type');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been using the commerce API so well, except for the last step. If your gift is a [Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/product/src/Entity/Product.php?h=8.x-2.x) entity, it means that it implements [Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductInterface](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/commerce/tree/modules/product/src/Entity/ProductInterface.php?h=8.x-2.x).

This interface already has an function for accessing product variations: `getVariations()`.

You should be able to use `$variations = $gift->getVariations();` to obtain an array of product variations.